# Should I use “another” or “other” in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, determiners

Here are the sentences:

> There’s no *other words* for it.
>
> There’s no *another word* for it.
>
> There’s no *other word* for it.

I think the first sentence is **right**, the second is **less preferred**, and the third is **wrong** because “other” needs plural nouns.

Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

The correct form of your first sentence is:

> There are no other words for it.

We use **"other"** before **plural countable nouns and all uncountable nouns**.

We use **"another"** before **singular countable nouns**.

In your second sentence, "no" and "another" are mutually exclusive determiners and we can't use both of them in front of the same noun.

Your third sentence is also fine. Yes, when you use "other" in a non-negative and non-pre-quantified structure, you should use a **plural noun** after "other" (*so it's not correct to say "there is other word"*), but there is nothing wrong with "one other word" or "no other word".

Answer (score 1):

Let me summarize your phrases and also add some more variations.

In the negative:

> ✔ There **are** no **other words** for it.
>   ✔ There **are** not **other words** for it.
>   ✔ There **is** no **other word** for it.
>   ✘ There **is** not **other word** for it.
>
> ✘ There **are** ***no*** **another** words for it.
>   ✘ There **are** ***not*** **another** words for it.
>   ✘ There **is** ***no*** **another word** for it.
>   ✔ There **is** ***not*** **another word** for it.

You can use **other** with both singular and plural nouns after **no**, and you can use **other** with plural nouns after **not**.

You can only use **another** with singular nouns after **not**.

---

In the positive:

> ✔ There **are other words** for it.
>   ✘ There **is other word** for it.
>
> ✘ There **are another words** for it.
>   ✔ There **is another word** for it.

You can only use **other** with plural nouns, and you can only use **another** with singular nouns.

Answer (score -1):

In the first option, the plural form of "word" should not be used since you are using "there's". The correct sentence with plural form would be :
There are no other words for it.
(This implies that there are no other words apart from two or more words.)

The second option is grammatically incorrect. "Another" cannot be used here.

The third option is correct. 
(This implies that there are no other words apart from a single word.)